# Get Emoji Count In String

Tags: android, android-edittext, character, emoji

I would like to find how many emojis the user has input into an `EditText`. If the user only enters emojis, and uses 3 or less, I want to be able to display that string within the app with a larger font.

Right now I did come across this post which does help detect if emojis are present in the string, but I have not been able to figure out how to count the number of emojis.

[Detecting if a character in a String is an emoticon (using Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392969/detecting-if-a-character-in-a-string-is-an-emoticon-using-android)

Does anyone know how I can get the emoji count from a String?

Answer (score 7):

Another approach would be to take advantage of `EmojiCompat`. This code presumes you initialized `EmojiCompat` when your app was starting up. The basic idea here is to have `EmojiCompat` process your `CharSequence`, inserting instances of `EmojiSpan` wherever any emoji appear, and then examine the results, returning a count of the `EmojiSpan` instances in the processed `Spannable`.

```
public static int getEmojiCount(CharSequence charSequence) {
    int count = 0;
    CharSequence processed = EmojiCompat.get().process(charSequence, 0, charSequence.length() -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, EmojiCompat.REPLACE_STRATEGY_ALL);
    if (processed instanceof Spannable) {
        Spannable spannable = (Spannable) processed;
        count = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length() - 1, EmojiSpan.class).length;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Do not forget to add dependency in app gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    int emojiCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length(); i++) {
     int type = Character.getType(yourString.charAt(i));
      if (type == Character.SURROGATE || type == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
       emojiCount++;
      }
    }

return emojiCount/2;
```

Comment: Will it count other weird Unicode characters as emoji?

Comment: Yes.

For strictly emojis, use:

if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(char) == Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS){
//emoji entered
}

Requires API >= 19

Comment: @RohanTaneja So, if API Level is 19 and above, I can just simply use `Character.UnicodeBlock.of(char) == Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS`?

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this was to import this library:

```
implementation 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:4.0.0'
```

Then I created a utility method to get the length of a string counting emojis as 1:

```
fun getLengthWithEmoji(s: String): Int{
        var emojiCount = EmojiParser.extractEmojis(s).size;
        var noEmojiString = EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(s);
        var emojiAndStringCount = emojiCount + noEmojiString.length;
        return emojiAndStringCount;
}
```

Generally to 'Get emoji count in string' I would use this line:

```
var emojiCount = EmojiParser.extractEmojis(s).size;
```

This accounts for all the latest emojis (depending on how up to date your library it). Check for some of the forks that others have made on the library as they in some cases have added missing emoji patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me was [codePointCount method](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_codepointcount.asp)

For example this method returns 1 if text value is "":

```
    fun getLengthWithEmoji(name: String): Int {
        return name.codePointCount(0, name.length)
    }
```

Comment: "‍" this case would not return 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (length < 100) {
                    if (count > 0 && after <= 0)/*remove emoij*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "emoij -> down length");
                        length--;
                    } else if (count > after)/*remove text*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "text -> down length");
                        length--;
                    } else if (count == 0 && after > 1)/*emoij*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "emoij -> increase");
                        ++length;
                    } else if (count == 0 && after == 1)/*Text*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "text -> increase");
                        ++length;
                    } else if (count > 0 && after > 1) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "text -> increase");
                        ++length;
                    }
                    if (s.length() <= 0)
                        length = 0;
                    Log.w("MainActivity", " Length: " + length);
                } else {
                    if (count > 0 && after <= 0)/*remove emoij*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "emoij -> down length");
                        length--;
                    } else if (count > after)/*remove text*/ {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "text -> down length");
                        length--;
                    }
                     Log.w("MainActivity", " Length: " + length);
                }

                if (length == 100) {
                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(s.length())});
                } else {
                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{});
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun String.lengthWithEmoji():Int{
        var count=0;
        this.forEach {
            if(isEmoji(it))
                count++
            }
       return (this.length-(count/2))
    }


    fun isEmoji(char:Char): Boolean {
        val type = Character.getType(char)
        return type == Character.SURROGATE.toInt() 
    }
```