# Find out text length containing emojis

Tags: android

How to find out `text length` containing emojis with normal text. I want to `limit` `Edittext` for maximum 20 characters. But when I add a new stylish emoji, `text length` reaches it's limit or sometimes it exceeds.

So I want to count 1 for a emoji. Please let me know if you have idea.

Comment: Here is something for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505866/how-to-limit-max-characters-in-edittext-with-emoji-inputs-allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be to scan the user input using a TextWatcher and compare against a known list of emoji UTF characters counting a matched set as one character. Here's a list to get you started (I don't know how up to date it is though) https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode